# Universal app runs at iphone resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an app which I am trying to pass through the apple review process.

They rejected my app for looking bad on ipad with iphone resolution.
I then adjusted the app so that it would run on iPad resolution in the iPad.
However the apple reviewer still sees it as iphone resolution on the iPad.

These are my settings:
[image]

Why is the apple reviewer seeing my app as iphone resolution on ipad ?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information. What have you done with your storyboards? What do **you** see when you run the app on an iPad?

Comment: I see the app at the iPad resolution